# How can I override browser CSS for autfilled inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

When autofilled, my input elements have a browser default style that I want to change. However, the browser styles all use `!important` and I can't seem to override them, even with a more specific selector that also uses `!important`. I think the exact styles that are causing the problem are these ones:

[Screenshot of styles from dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC749.png)

Is there a way to *override* them, either with CSS or JavaScript? I'm certain that I've seen input elements with custom autofill styles before. In case that's important - even though I want the override to work in all browsers anyways - I'm currently using Brave, which runs on Chromium, so selectors etc. should be the same that work for Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Javascript to solve this, and as a rule of thumb, you should use as less JS to manipulate your CSS as possible,

you can use the `-webkit-autofill` pseudo-selector to target those fields and style them as you see fit. The default styling only affects the background colour, but most other properties apply here, such as border and `font-size`. You can even change the colour of the text using `-webkit-text-fill-colour`, which is included in the snippet below.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

** note that this snippet is just an example that I had in handy; you can use it in many ways! **

Comment: Thanks, that actually works! I have just one more question: Can I change the background color without using `box-shadow` and instead directly access the `background-color` property?

Comment: Yes, you can use any of these pseudo-elements as you like.